# Run time error 3075 - missing operator

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a run-time error 3075 on the following SQL query. I am trying to carry out in MS Access 2010. The error message is telling me there is a syntax error (missing operator) on the join query. I cannot find it.

```
Private Sub comando21_dblclick(cancel As Integer)

Dim st_sql As String


st_sql = "INSERT INTO tblsearchengine01 (
   [id event],
   [id project],
   [id_project_phase],
   [owner],
   [contact], 
   [event],
   [type],
   [participant],
   [role_type],
   [commitment],
   [description],
   [identification_status],
   [overall_status],
   [status],
   [tblmasterlistofeventsnotes],
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistorynotes],
   [automatic user entry],
   [automatic date of entry],
   [automatic_user_entry],
   [automatic_date_of_entry],
   [expected start date],
   [actual start date],
   [expected completion date],
   [actual completion date],
   [effective date],
   [priority]
)  SELECT 
   [tblmasterlistofevents].
   [id event],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[id project],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[id_project_phase],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[owner],
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[contact],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[event],
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[type],
   [tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants].[participant],
   [tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants].[role_type],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[commitment],
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[description],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[identification_status],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[overall_status],
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[status],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[notes],
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[notes],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[automatic user entry],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[automatic date of entry], 
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[automatic_user_entry],
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[automatic_date_of_entry],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[expected start date],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[actual start date],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[expected completion date],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[actual completion date],
   [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[effective date],
   [tblmasterlistofevents].[Priority]
 FROM [tblmasterlistofevents] 
   INNER JOIN [tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants] 
     ON [tblmasterlistofevents].[id event]=[tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants].[ID_Event] 
   INNER JOIN [tblmasterlistofeventshistory] 
     ON [tblmasterlistofevents].[id event]=[tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[ID_Event]"



Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

End Sub
```

Comment: You've asked 40 questions... have you really not learnt how to format your post yet? You have 2 FROM clauses in your query...

Comment: Sorry Ben, i tried to edit the code to be indented but I didn't have the option to do so..  I must of missed something. I will be more alert next time.   The from clause is listed only once, (originally there was an additional from clause but in comment format)

Comment: Ben, as you can see I am not that great with this site (but I am Learning).. Would you happen to have a bit of time for a chat??  or if you dont have time maybe a few questions via email (i cant find your address)   I have a couple of generic, high level questions that I think you may be able to help me with....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your `from` clause:

```
FROM [tblmasterlistofevents] INNER JOIN
     [tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants]
     ON [tblmasterlistofevents].[id event] = [tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants].[ID_Event] INNER JOIN
     [tblmasterlistofeventshistory]
     ON [tblmasterlistofevents].[id event]= [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[ID_Event]
```

When you do multiple joins, Access requires parentheses.  Try this:

```
FROM ([tblmasterlistofevents] INNER JOIN
      [tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants]
      ON [tblmasterlistofevents].[id event] = [tblprojmanagementphaseparticipants].[ID_Event]
     ) INNER JOIN
     [tblmasterlistofeventshistory]
     ON [tblmasterlistofevents].[id event]= [tblmasterlistofeventshistory].[ID_Event]
```